# Error: No provider for e! with prod flag(working fine in local server) angular4

Tags: angular, npm

Can someone tell me the solutions
here is my code?
working fine with local server,
when I move to **hosting server** the following error arises.

```
Error: No provider for e!
at _e (vendor.c6cd506179cfc8072419.bundle.js:1)
at vendor.c6cd506179cfc8072419.bundle.js:1
at e._throwOrNull (vendor.c6cd506179cfc8072419.bundle.js:1)
at e._getByKeyDefault (vendor.c6cd506179cfc8072419.bundle.js:1)
at e._getByKey (vendor.c6cd506179cfc8072419.bundle.js:1)
at e.get (vendor.c6cd506179cfc8072419.bundle.js:1)
at wo (vendor.c6cd506179cfc8072419.bundle.js:1)
at vendor.c6cd506179cfc8072419.bundle.js:1
at Mo (vendor.c6cd506179cfc8072419.bundle.js:1)
at wo (vendor.c6cd506179cfc8072419.bundle.js:1)
```

### versions

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 6.10.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 4.4.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router, tsc-wrapped

@angular/cdk: 5.2.5
@angular/cli: 1.7.4
@angular/material: 5.2.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.3.4
webpack: 3.11.0
```

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "cemsdemo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 7777 --host 192.168.0.169 --open",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.6",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^2.0.0-beta.15",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^2.0.0-beta.15",
    "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^0.6.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.6",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
    "angular4-datepicker": "^1.0.1",
    "angular4-slimscroll": "^1.0.5",
    "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.6",
    "firebase": "^4.13.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "ng2-owl-carousel": "^0.1.15",
    "ngx-loading": "^1.0.14",
    "ngx-mydatepicker": "^2.4.5",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.1.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.10",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.4.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.109",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Can someone tell me the solutions
here is my code?
working fine with local server,
when I move to **hosting server** the following error arises.

When I go with non prod flag its working fine,But I personally feel to get better performance factors wish to go with prod environment.

Answer (score 1):

Since it works fine on your PC, this tells me that some library that exists on your PC is missing on the hosting server where you deploy your app. Some of your packages in the devDependency section are shown as an empty string what are those?

Also, since the error message refers to a single-letter variable e, I can assume that you did a production build where uglify.js renamed all the variables. So try to do a build without the --prod option and deploy it on your hosting server. It may give you a more readable error message.

Comment: Thank you for your response.Updated the question and added the missing content in the json and version in the above data.Kindly look into it and tell me where i went wrong?

Comment: So the issue is not on the hosting server, but in the prod build. The next step to try is to keep the prod build, but turn off the AoT compilation.

ng build --prod --aot false